# MS Access - Search by Text Box

Tags: ms-access

I'm relatively new to Microsoft Access but I've been using the same code below from another database and replacing it with the ones you see below.

```
strsearch = Me.txtSearch.Value
Task = "SELECT * FROM t_Cases WHERE ((CaseID Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (ActiveYN Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (ClaimType Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (HousingLocation ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (GrievanceAddress Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = Task
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

There is a text box named `txtsearch` and the records on the form are meant to be filtered on the written text box selection. However, I'm getting a `runtime error '3075'` stating syntax error (missing operator) in the query expression. Can someone please help me identify what is the syntax error in this? I thank you greatly for any assistance you can offer.

Jon

Comment: Your expression has two assignment operators and it refers to strSearch on both sides of the first assignment. It can't be fixed unless you provide more info.

Comment: What additional information do I need to provide in order to identify which assignment operator to remove?

Comment: You need to provide a lot because what you posted cannot possibly be used in / taken from another database.

Comment: @nincomp The original VBA code from the previous database is listed here. Private Sub Command30_Click()

strsearch = Me.txtSearch.Value
Task = "SELECT * FROM T_RequestToFillMaster WHERE ((TrackingNumber Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (CivilServiceClassification Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (Budgeted Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (Division Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (Active Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (Shift Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"") OR (PositionNumber Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"
Me.RecordSource = Task
Me.OrderByOn = True

Comment: @nincomp The tables from the previous database are very similar to the ones I've been creating and the form is a dynamic recordset type. I'm sorry for how new I am at this and my inability to explain better.

Comment: Don't put code in comments (unreadable)! Edit your question!

Answer (score 0):

With an operator (e.g.: `=,<,>,LIKE`) you can compare two values.

You are missing a `LIKE`after `HousingLocation`

```vb
Task = "SELECT * FROM t_Cases WHERE ((CaseID Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"")" & _
  " OR (ActiveYN Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"")" & _
  " OR (ClaimType Like ""*" & strsearch & "*"")" & _
  " OR (HousingLocation LIKE ""*" & strsearch & "*"")" & _
  " OR (GrievanceAddress Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's never use simple concatenation with user input. If a user input contains `"` then we have a syntax error in our query.

Let's use BuildCriteria function.

```
Dim strsearch As String
    strsearch = Me.txtSearch.Value

Dim filters(0 To 4) As String
    filters(0) = BuildCriteria("CaseID", dbText, strsearch)
    filters(1) = BuildCriteria("ActiveYN", dbText, strsearch)
    filters(2) = BuildCriteria("ClaimType", dbText, strsearch)
    filters(3) = BuildCriteria("HousingLocation", dbText, strsearch)
    filters(4) = BuildCriteria("GrievanceAddress", dbText, strsearch)

Dim filter As String
    filter = Join(filters, " OR ")

Dim Task As String
    Task = "SELECT * FROM t_Cases WHERE " & filter

Me.RecordSource = Task
Me.OrderByOn = True
```